# Is there a way to get this code to run after the user hits enter instead of having to type yes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
import random

roll_again = "yes"

while roll_again == "yes" or roll_again == "y":  print(random.randint(0,6),random.randint(0,6),random.randint(0,6),random.randint(0,6),random.randint(0,6),end=' ')

roll_again = input("Roll the dices again?")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply just try and the question after your print in the while loop and create a checking mechanism, whether they type in 'y' or 'n'

```
import random

roll_again = "yes"

while roll_again == "yes" or roll_again == "y":

    print(random.randint(0,6))
    roll_again = input("Roll the dices again? Enter y or n.")
    if roll_again == "y":
        continue
    elif roll_again == "n":
        break
```

I hope i was able to help you, but if you have any questions, just ask! :)

Comment: Thank you!! I now have the code printing the five numbers and it will run again if I enter yes. Is there a way I can run it again by just hitting the enter key and not putting anything in?

Comment: FYI, "code snippets" are for HTML or JavaScript that can be run in a browser -- for other languages, use the `{}` button in the editor for formatting. (This is why your code was highlighted as HTML, not Python).

Answer (score 0):

To make the loop execute until something other than "yes" or "y" is entered, remove the `break` line and put the `roll_again = input("...")` line inside the while loop.

To print multiple things, you can separate them with a comma, e.g. `print(1, 2, 3, 4)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the roll_again inside the while loop. It does not need a break as it will exit when you enter anything but your specified keys. This also assumes you want to roll once at the start every time, but if you want the user to specify first also you can copy the input to where you set `roll_again = "yes"`

```
import random

roll_again = "yes"
while roll_again is "yes" or roll_again is "y":
    print(random.randint(0,6))
    roll_again = input("Roll the dices again?")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main question about how to get the loop to run every time you say you want it to is pretty simple. Just move the place where you're asking for user intput inside your loop and get rid of the `break` statement:

```
while roll_again == "yes" or roll_again == "y":

    print(random.randint(0,6))
    # don't break here
    roll_again = input("Roll the dices again?") # indent this to be in the loop
```

As for printing multiple numbers, there are a variety of ways you could do it. The most basic would be to simply repeat your call to `randint` several times in the `print` call, but that would be a bit awkward if the number of rolls you want is large. A better solution is probably to use a list comprehension:

```
print([random.randint(6) for _ in range(5)])
```

This will print out with square brackets. If you don't want that, you could put a `*` in front of the opening square bracket in the comprehension, so that the values are unpacked as separate arguments to `print`. You could also use `str.join`, but you'd need to convert each number to a string before they can be joined together.